# How to download file from firebase storage and turn it into .stl file with react?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, three.js, firebase-storage

I am trying to download a file I stored on firebase storage and then turn it into an stl file to be later used by ThreeJs.
Currently I am trying to use the following code but it results in a file with 0 size:

```
const [blobData, setBlobData] = useState([]);
  const storageRef = storageReference(
    storage,
    '/storage/testModel.stl',
  )
  if (blobData.length < 1) {
    getBlob(storageRef).then((data) => {setBlobData(data)}); 
    var testFile = new File([blobData], "testFile.stl");
  }
  console.log("Outside Loop",testFile);
```

What the log outside the loop logs is the following:
[image: log]

Is there a better way to do this or can I use this code with changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the STLLoader from react three fiber and it turnes out you can give the URL from firebase storage directly to this loader.